# datetime switching timezone from google app script to google sheets intentionally

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, time

I'm trying to fill some google sheets cells with the current date and time, date is ok, but the time is off by 6 hours.
This is the code I used:

```
      function start() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var timestamp = new Date();
      Logger.log('start, timestamp: ' + timestamp);
      var date = Utilities.formatDate(timestamp, 'Europe/Brussels', "dd/MM/yyyy");
      Logger.log('date: ' + date);
      var time = Utilities.formatDate(timestamp, 'Europe/Brussels', "HH:mm:ss");
      Logger.log('time: ' + time);
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(SheetName);
      sheet.appendRow([date,time]);
    }
```

The logs of the date and time do give me the expected date and time, but once the appendRow is done, in Google Sheets, I'm getting the offset time...
I have tried to offset it myself, to correct to the right value, but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is odd, I tested your code and it works for me.

[image: Original Script]

[image: Sheet]

It's properly showing the timezone of 'Europe/Brussels'. Also, tested using `var time = Utilities.formatDate(timestamp, 'GMT+1', "HH:mm:ss");` and both display the correct time inside the `Execution log` and the cell.

[image: GMT+1]

[image: Sheet GMT+1]

If you test the code in a new Apps Script does it show the incorrect time zone too? Have you reviewed the time timezone inside `Project Settings` > `General Settings`?

[image: Project Settings]

If after all that you still have the same issue, I will recommend creating an issue tracker by following the steps [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#developer_product_feedback).

Comment: Thanks for testing, the timezone setting in your last screenshot was indeed wrong, and by exactly 6 hours, so I thought I got it. But after setting it to the correct zone, nothing changed. I put the piece of code in a fresh script, with only that code, executed it, and bam, it works. No idea what did it, no idea what the difference is, but I'm going to try and reconfigure to give this function a seperate file.

Comment: @pieter-jangoeman, It might be caching the wrong time zone somewhere in the Apps Script and that is why it is working in the new one. You can try to clear cache and cookies or try later on to see if it propagates the change of timezone.

Comment: I'll try that indeed, because I just tried again, same main file, function in seperate file, same issue.

Comment: @pieter-jangoeman, were you able to make it work?

Comment: @pieter-jangoeman  if Giselle's answer actually worked for you (at least for your initial concern), don't forget to either upvote or mark it as 'best answer'. By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.

Comment: It works! I had two issues, Giselle gave me a solution to one, the other was that it seems that saving doesn't really update the code that's running when you execute the app from a web link.i had to implement every change...

Answer (score 0):

I'm based in London/UK.

I also had an issue where the locale time showed correct in Google Apps Script logs but changed to MST (UTC-7) when the data was written to Google Sheets, despite the Locale and Time Zone in the sheet settings being set to the UK.

I fixed this by changing the TimeZone to another one (saving) and then back again to UK/London. Why that worked I don't know, but now when I write data to the sheet, the time zone is correct.